# Storing longitude and latitude data in android

Tags: android, database, latitude-longitude

I have to store **longitude and latitude of all cities** of a country in android application

when user will select a city i have to return the longitude and latitude of selected city.

what will be the most efficient way to do this?

or is there any resources where i enter a country and it will show all cities with their longitude and latitude..?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Fetch data from server using XML parsing or Json parsing. You can also use SQLITE database.

Comment: App will not use internet service. 
So  i have to save manually all longitude and latitude by search from internet to my app?

Like search longitude and latitude of a city and save into app.?\

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Geocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

For example :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Berlin&sensor=true
And parse output using GSON

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Berlin",
               "short_name" : "Berlin",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Berlin",
               "short_name" : "Berlin",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Niemcy",
               "short_name" : "DE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Berlin, Niemcy",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.6754542,
                  "lng" : 13.7611176
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.33962959999999,
                  "lng" : 13.0911663
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52000659999999,
               "lng" : 13.404954
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.6754542,
                  "lng" : 13.7611176
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.33962959999999,
                  "lng" : 13.0911663
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```